How do I define a graph labeling function?
I have a tuple $\tau = (\tau_1, \tau_2, ... \tau_n)$ and I want to represent $\tau$ as a labeled directed cycle graph $\mathcal{C}_{|\tau|}$, where nodes of the graph are labeled uniquely. Would it be correct to say that the graph $\mathcal{C}_{|\tau|}$ is labeled according to the mapping function $l: \tau \rightarrow \{0,1,...,|\tau|\}$?
So the corresponding path to $\tau$ in $\mathcal{C}_n$ would be the sequence of edges from node $l(\tau_1)$ to $l(\tau_2)$ to $l(\tau_3)$, and so on.
Thanks in advance.

What are the elements of $\tau$? What limitations are there on what can serve as a label? Also, what's the goal behind encoding a tuple as a cycle graph?

@GregNisbet I have a tuple $\tau$ and a set of tuples $\mathcal{A}$. The goal is to describe an algorithm that decides whether $\tau$ is the rotation of any tuple in $\mathcal{A}$. I considered representing $\tau$ as a directed cycle graph, and checking whether any tuple in $\mathcal{A}$ corresponds to a Hamiltonian path of $\mathcal{C}_{|\tau|}$. There are no limitations on the elements of the tuples - they can contain duplicate elements, for example, $(a,a,b,c)$.

Are graphs a fundamental aspect of the problem (i.e. are you given the ability to answer certain graph questions quickly by the framework of the question) or are they just a tool that you're using to produce an algorithm that operates on sequences of symbols, or something else?

They are just a tool to produce an algorithm.

You should edit your question to include the context that you provided in the comments, since it's important to interpreting the question. I redid my answer to provide an explicit algorithm, which is basically just canonicalizing the tuples into a different alphabet in such a way that tuples that are rotations of each other canonicalize to the same thing.

@GregNisbet Thank you for taking the time to understand and provide a detailed answer. I still want to solve this using graphs, but since the tuple could contain duplicates, I needed a labeling function that maps each element to a unique label. Thus, my question was how to formally define such a function. Your earlier answer was more helpful in this regard. While I mentioned that graphs are just a tool (for now), they are our preferred method as they might yield interesting results, later.

Why do you absolutely need a graph? Canonization is the way to go, associate each letter to a number, and find the smallest cyclic permutation of the string (thia is equivalent to find the smallest suffix string, after concatenation of two copies of your string, this can be computed in linear time)

If $\mathcal{A}$ is fixed and you want to query many $\tau$, the admissible $\tau$ form a regular language so you can construct the automaton recognizing this language. With this approach, you will even have a graph (but on more than $n$ vertices...)

In fact, this is simpler than an automaton, you just build a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with all the cyclic permutations of all the words in $\mathcal{A}$, and to query a string $\tau$, you just query the trie. If you care about efficiency (and that $n$ is big), the trie can be built efficiently by using a linear time suffix trie algorithm (to deal with the cyclic permutations).

So, as it turns out, the graph theory bit is a bit of a red herring.
Really, you have a set of tuples $\mathcal{A}$ and you're trying to quickly determine whether a new tuple $\tau$ is a rotation of an element of $\mathcal{A}$ or not.
Here's the simplest algorithm that I can think of.
First, we define a way to canonicalize your tuples and then store them in some kind of data structure.
Here's a way I can think of to canonicalize a tuple that involves translating it into another alphabet $\mathbb{N} \times \Sigma$. This is equivalent to a run-length encoding.

Combine adjacent identical symbols together, so $[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]$ maps to $[(1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0)]$.
If the first and last symbols are the same, combine them by moving the last element to the front. So $[(1, 0), (2, 1)]$ maps to $[(3, 0), (2, 1)]$.
Now our tuple contains no adjacent duplicates, so find the smallest element of $\mathbb{N} \times \Sigma$ (in lexicographic order) and move it around to the front. So, $[(3, 0), (2, 1)]$ maps to $[(2, 1), (3, 0)]$ since we compare the number of repetitions first (although this choice is arbitrary).
The tuple is now canonicalized.

Now you can store your canonicalized tuples in a hash table or a trie or some other data structure.

I cannot see how this current algorithm preserves the order of tuple elements; for example, consider the tuple $[0,1,1,0,2,0,0]$. After step 3 of the algorithm, it would be transformed to $[(3,0), (2,1), (1,0), (1,2)]$. After step 4, which involves moving the smallest element of $\mathbb{N} \times \Sigma$ to the front, the result would be $[(1,0), (3,0), (2,1), (1,2)]$. Am I missing something?
